# get max date/time between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I would like to query a table for several fields between two dates/times, and I need to determine the max date and time between two date/times.

The table contains these types of fields:
validtime|datavalue|basistime|pe1|pe2|t|s|lid

The validtime is the date/time that is valid for a datavalue whereas the basistime is the date/time that the datavalue was created. I need to find the max(basistime) between two date/times.

This is what I have as of right now, but without success:

```
SELECT validtime, datavalue, max(basistime) from ped where lid='XXXXX' and
and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and t='C' and s='Z' and basistime>='2014-11-19 
12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-19 23:45:00' group by ped.validtime,        
ped.datavalue, ped.basistime;
```

I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT validtime, datavalue, (SELECT MAX(basistime) from ped where
lid='XXXXX' and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and t='C' and s='Z' and 
basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-19 23:45:00')
from ped where lid='XXXXX' and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and t='C' and s='Z'
and basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-19 23:45:00'; 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT basistime, validtime, datavalue, lid, 
pe1, pe2, t, s, from ped where lid='XXXXX' and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and t='C'
and s='Z' and basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-19
23:45:00' group by ped.validtime, ped.datavalue; SELECT t.validtime,
t.datavalue from temp t where t.lid='XXXXX' and t.basistime=max(t.basistime) 
order by validtime ASC;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT max(basistime), validtime, datavalue,      
lid, pe1, pe2, t, s, from ped where lid='XXXXX' and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and 
t='C' and s='Z' and basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-     
19 23:45:00'; SELECT t.validtime, t.datavalue from temp t where     
t.lid='XXXXX' and t.basistime=max(t.basistime) order by validtime ASC;
```

I have also experimented with casting the basistime as text and using BETWEEN for the 2 dates.

Most of the above queries produce no data. The first one I posted produces data, but the dates are from 2009 (obviously not in between the 2 dates I provided).

The desired result would be output such as:
validtime, datavalue, max(basistime)

I have read every entry I could find on stackoverflow and otherwise, but I am not finding a solution as of yet. Thank you so very much in advance for your assistance.

Comment: an example of your data in table form would be useful.  Maybe set up a SQLfiddle?  http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you want the max(basistime)  you don't must add this column to group by

```
SELECT validtime, datavalue, max(basistime) 
from ped 
where lid='XXXXX' 
and pe1='H'
and pe2='G' 
and t='C' 
and s='Z' 
and basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' 
and basistime<'2014-11-19 23:45:00' 
group by validtime,  datavalue
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much, everyone. It turned out to be a combination of two relatively simple things. As scaisEdge mentioned, I needed to add the basistime to the group by section and I was also missing some parentheses. Here's the final version:

```
SELECT validtime, datavalue, max(basistime) from ped 
where lid='XXXXX' and pe1='H' and pe2='G' and t='C' and s='Z' 
and (basistime>='2014-11-19 12:00:00' and basistime<'2014-11-19 23:45:00') 
group by validtime,datavalue,basistime
order by validtime;
```